# Hide "Last change" field in webtrees

Tags: webtrees

I'm using the newest version of [webtrees](https://www.webtrees.net/index.php/en/) (1.7.9) and even though I have *Control panel > Manage family trees > Preferences > Lists > The date and time of the last update* set to `Hide`, I can clearly see that field in the `Facts and events` sections of each person's record.

Is there any way to truly hide this entry field?

Answer (score 1):

The solution:

1. Go to Control Panel. Select `Family Trees` > `Manage` > `Privacy`.
2. Scroll down to the bottom of page, to `Privacy Restrictions`. Click `Add`.
3. Select `Last Change` as fact or event.
4. Set the access level to `Hide from anyone`. Save changes.

This way you can control visibility of many other elements in webtrees.

All the glory for this solution goes to [*bertkoor*](https://www.webtrees.net/index.php/en/forum/help-for-ver-1-7-9/31989-solved-hide-last-change-field-in-webtrees#63706).